# Neo4j inserting large files - huge difference in time between

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am inserting a set of files (pdfs, of each 2 MB) in my database.
Inserting 100 files at once takes +- 15 seconds, while inserting 250 files at once takes 80 seconds.

I am not quite sure why this big difference is happening, but I assume it is because the amount of free memory is full between this amount. Could this be the problem? 
If there is any more detail I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: Neo4j was not built for storing binary data, so that can be the reason.

Comment: That is a good point, but it is always worth a try. It supports a byte[] type though, and I thought that for small files, it wouldn't be a problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure of what is happening on your side but it really looks like what is described [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html#_write_performance) in the neo4j performance guide.

It could be:

**Memory issues**

> If you are experiencing poor write performance after writing some data
>   (initially fast, then massive slowdown) it may be the operating system
>   that is writing out dirty pages from the memory mapped regions of the
>   store files. These regions do not need to be written out to maintain
>   consistency so to achieve highest possible write speed that type of
>   behavior should be avoided.

**Transaction size**

Are you using multiple transactions to upload your files ?

> Many small transactions result in a lot of I/O writes to disc and
>   should be avoided. Too big transactions can result in OutOfMemory
>   errors, since the uncommitted transaction data is held on the Java
>   Heap in memory.

If you are on linux, they also suggest some tuning to improve performance. See [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/linux-performance-guide.html).

You can look up the details on the page.

Also, if you are on linux, you can check memory usage by yourself during import by using this command:

```
$ free -m
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you, haven't seen the memory issues post.